# Drawing lines in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

I wrote program in assembly language which suspposed to draw 8 horizontal lines. But I have a problem. My 5th line doesn't show. Every line should have length 320 and height 25. In CX I have the end of the line and in BX the beginning of the line. Every line should be red. But the 5th line is black.

The code for drawing the lines look like this:

```
Draw PROC
    MOV ax, 0a000h
    MOV ES, AX
    MOV BX, CX
    ADD CX, 8000
etDraw:
    MOV al, 4
    MOV ES:[BX], AL
    INC BX
    CMP BX, CX
    JL etDraw
    RET
ENDP
```

Using procedure:

```
    MOV AX, 0f00h
    INT 10h
    MOV ax, 0013H
    int 10h
    MOV ah, 0Ch
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    CALL Draw
    MOV ah, 08h
    int 21h
    mov ax, 0f00h
    int 10h
    mov ax, 0003h
    int 10h
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
```

Comment: You should show the code where you call this procedure.

Comment: @Michael just done

Comment: I don't see any calls to `Draw` in that code you added.

Comment: Why aren't you assigning any value to `cx` before calling `Draw`, since `Draw` seems to depend on that?

Comment: And since you're really just filling the entire screen with a single color, you could replace all of those `Draw` calls with something like `mov ax,0a000h` `mov es,ax` `xor di,di` `mov ecx,16000` `mov eax,04040404h` `cld` `rep stosd`

Comment: I don't want to repalce Draw, i have to have it in program, because it will be something bigger. I only have probelm with this black fragment in it.  It's  the only thing i don't understand and with witch i need some help. There is mov cx, 0 before everything in code

Comment: Well, there's also the fact that you use `jl` (signed `<`) when you should be using `jb` (unsigned `<`) or `jne`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you compare addresses in `Draw` to see if you've reached the end of your line, you using `JL` ("Jump Less"), which is a *signed* comparison. You should be using an unsigned comparison (`JB`, "Jump Below") or check for equality with `JE` or `JZ`.

This only happens on your 5th line because that is where the end address rolls over from a positive to a negative number (when it is considered as a signed number).  Specifically,

```
4 * 8000 = 32000
5 * 8000 = 40000, but with 16 bit signed numbers this will be -25536.
```

With the 5th line, BX starts as 32000, CX starts as -25536, so you'll get one pixel set and the `JL` won't jump (because 32001 > -25536).

Remember that whenever you compare addresses, these should almost always be unsigned comparisons (`JB`, `JA`).